# Filtering an array based on database records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, activerecord

I have an `Array` if a user's Facebook friend list as follows:

```
[
  { 'name' => 'John Mallock', 'id' => '123123' },
  { 'name' => 'Susan Freely', 'id' => '123123123' },
  ...
]
```

I'd like to filter this list for entries that exist in the `users` table in my Rails app. I'm currently doing this as follows:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new 'access_token'
friends = graph.get_connections 'me', 'friends' # Returns the structure above
friends.select! { |f| User.exists? :facebook_id => f['id'] }
```

This results in a `SELECT` query for every friend in the list, which is noticeably inefficient.

Is there a more effective means of filtering this list based on database records?

Comment: Build up an array of all of the ids and check for them all at once.  Then you'll have an array of the users, and an array of the existing ids.  From that point, you just filter.  (Posted as a comment because I don't know Ruby or the FB API, so am hoping there's nothing I've overlooked.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to pass an array into a `where` method in ruby. If you pass in an array, it will be converted into a `IN` query on the database:

```
users = User.where(:facebook_id => friends.map{|f| f['id']})

# generates: SELECT * FROM users where users.facebook_id IN (f1, f2, etc..)
```

If you need to know which entries in `friends` correspond to users, you could then call a select on friends:

```
existing_facebook_ids = users.map(&:facebook_id)
friends.select! {|f| existing_facebook_ids.include?(f['id'])}
```

Note that the above is pretty inefficient if you have a decent amount of records in either array. You'd probably want to optimize it somewhat, or better yet, don't use the friends array and just iterate over User records if they contain the same data.

Comment: I agree that it's inefficient, but it will work for the time being. Thanks for the help. This reduced my queries from 1/friend to 1 in total. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL `IN` query to select all the IDs at once.

```
friend_ids = friends.map{|f| f['id']}
User.scoped(:conditions => ['id IN (?)', friend_ids])
```